# How to reference external dll and xml comments in dotnet core

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

[image]

So i am using this

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="..\bibliotecas\ByteBank.Modelos.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to reference an external api, and its working but i can't see the comments from the xml.

How to reference the XML file of an external api on dotnet.core ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc).

Basically, you need to config `GenerateDocumentationFile` element to the `<PropertyGroup>` section of your `.csproj` project file:

```
<GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
```

And try to add a `dll` reference like below:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="ByteBank.Modelos">
    <HintPath>..\bibliotecas\ByteBank.Modelos.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks but i already have the Xml from the other project, i don't know how to import it to this project.

Comment: @ThiagoRamos Put the `xml` file in the same place as `dll` file.

Comment: it's already on the same place, the folder have the dll and xml. I can use the dll classes on my visual studio code but can't see their comments. So i don't know if it's importing the xml file or only dll.

Comment: I've added an image to the post.

Comment: @ThiagoRamos That should work, how about you try to restart VS code? p.s: What's that error means?

Comment: The error was me trying to add a direct reference to a XML : <Reference Include="..\bibliotecas\ByteBank.Modelos.XML" />.
I restarted the computer but still don't work the documentation.

On the project that is the origin of the api i can see the docs, but on the external i can't.

Comment: Also, thank you a lot for all the atention that you are giving to me.

Comment: @ThiagoRamos No worries, and I've made an update to my answer, check it out to find out if it helps.

Comment: I saw, still does not works, i don't know if i need to reference explicitly the xml file or how to do it.

Comment: @ThiagoRamos There is no need to add a reference to the `xml` file for this purpose.

Comment: Do the vscode need some extension to this?

Comment: ITS WORKING NOW, i don't know why but the file is genereted as .XML, i just has changed to .xml to test and VOA LA, work. Just want to know why the default generations is XML. Thanks a lot for all you attention.

Comment: @ThiagoRamos That's great.